# Google AdMob Podfile - Manual vs Auto Version Update?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, cocoapods

OK, apologies if this may come across as a 'green' question ...

I have incorporated the Google AdMob SDK via CocoaPods successfully.

My pod file looks like:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
```

So my Podfile should automatically 'grab' any version 'newer' than version 7.0.

I am still developing my app, and when I run tests on my physical device, I am presented with this type of message in the console:

> You are currently using version 7.8.0 of the SDK. Please
>   consider updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the
>   latest features and bug fixes. The latest SDK can be downloaded from
>   ....

So I run `Podinstall` command via the terminal targeting my relevant directory that holds my development app's latest Xcode project, and it updates all relevant Google Mobile Ad SDKs to the current version.

I guess while my app is not 'live', my Podfile is essentially inactive in terms of updating itself automatically.

**Question :** If I were to upload my project today to the App Store with my Podfile updated to the most current Google AdMob SDK version, will it automatically update my project to the most current version thereafter? Are the three (3) lines of code in my Podfile sufficient?

Many thanks and apologies in advance if this is an extremely basic question ;)

Comment: Please check this link once https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start#create_a_new_project and try the pod commands.

Comment: @SriKanth Do I have to adopt Firebase to display ads by AdMob? As I understand it, Firebase just provides an extra Ad Analytics layer for AdMob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly new to CocoaPods myself so I am not 100% what you mean with

"I guess while my app is not 'live', my Podfile is essentially inactive in terms of updating itself automatically."

I believe to update your Pods you need to run the Update command, it does not update itself automatically.

**If I were to upload my project today to the App Store with my Podfile updated to the most current Google AdMob SDK version, will it automatically update my project to the most current version thereafter?**

I believe no, you need to run podUpdate.

**Are the three (3) lines of code in my Podfile sufficient?**

Should be

This is how my pod files looks

```
  # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
  # platform :ios, '9.0'

  target 'MyGame (iOS)' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use     dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

   pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
   pod 'ChartboostSDK'

   # Pods for MyGame (iOS)

   target 'MyGame (iOS) Tests' do
   inherit! :search_paths
   # Pods for testing
   end

 end
```

CocoaPods actually released an app for OSX recently, which makes using it a lot easier

https://cocoapods.org/app

To read more update pod updates vs installs you should read this.

https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/pod-install-vs-update.html

Or a great swift tutorial from ray wenderlich

https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the content, the bundle should help me sort matters out for myself. Big tip of my hat to you kind Sir ;)